# Looping through the contents of a file, extracting data between two identifiers/tags

Tags: bash, macos, loops, awk, io

I want to divide one very large file into a number of smaller ones. Then I want to save each smaller file to its own directory.  I'm not familiar with Awk or Bash scripting.

My large data file has the structure shown below.  In it, "i" is a time step and "9" refers to the number of rows (data points) in each time step.

For each time step, I want to take everything (i.e., from and including "9" to the line above the next "9") and put it in its own file and own directory labeled according to the time step.  I would be very grateful for any advice.  If the question is not clear, I would be happy to modify it.

```
     9
i =        0
Ir         2.7122680189       11.056957424         6.8765696187
Ir         1.7122680189        7.0569574242        2.8765696187
Ir         10.1738894899      10.9594639697       10.1225475792
Ir         1.7122680189       10.5695742424        2.8765696187
Ir         0.8778827417       -0.5336942397        0.4088988234
XO         0.1738894899        6.9594639697       -2.1225475792
XO        -8.0921793354        6.4673780979        2.6251511813
XO        -5.1738894899       -0.9594639697       -7.1225475792
XO         4.1738894899       -7.9594639697       12.1225475792
     9
i =        1
Ir         2.7122680189       11.056957424         6.8765696187
Ir         1.7122680189        7.0569574242        2.8765696187
Ir         10.1738894899      10.9594639697       10.1225475792
Ir         1.7122680189       10.5695742424        2.8765696187
Ir         0.8778827417       -0.5336942397        0.4088988234
XO         0.1738894899        6.9594639697       -2.1225475792
XO        -8.0921793354        6.4673780979        2.6251511813
XO        -5.1738894899       -0.9594639697       -7.1225475792
XO         4.1738894899       -7.9594639697       12.1225475792
```

I have been able to figure out (roughly) how to make new directories for each time and copy other files I need into them, but not how to put my files of interest into them. E.g.

```
let TIMESTEPS=100000 
for ((time=0; time <= TIMESTEPS; time++)) 
do
     mkdir -p $time/timeData
     cp otherUsefulFile $time/
done
```

Comment: `awk` is a better choice for this.  Have you explored it?

Comment: Thank you.  I have used it for very simple tasks, but don't know enough about it to be familiar with its advantages/disadvantages.  I can look into it.  Are there any advantages in particular?

Comment: The script I proposed was aimed to be directly used as an `awk` script, and called `awk -f awk_script`. Here you added quotes around `BEGIN`

Comment: Yes, I added the quotes because the script didn't run without them.  I just removed the quotes around "BEGIN" and tried the call you suggested.  Thanks.  It ran until the flush_buff error I mentioned earlier.  I made an edit to the code in my question according to your last comment (function flush_buff(cur_dir"/test-pos.xyz). Same syntax error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Remove the hashbang (`#!/bin/bash`) and the `awk` keyword

Comment: Thanks, Zelnes.  Progress!  I updated the code in my question.  In addition to your latest suggestion above, I also removed "/" in the argument to "function flush_buff" because my test file is in the same directory the code is in.  Now the error is (see comment below):

Comment: awk: syntax error at source line 16 in function flush_buff source file dividePosFile.awk
 context is
      >>> yz" <<<  ) {
awk: bailing out at source line 40 in function flush_buff

Comment: @Ant please read carefully the syntax I used when declaring `function flush_buff(file)`. I say that `file` is a variable, filled when I call later `flush_buff(cur_dir "/file")` (note the `/`)

Comment: @Selnes, thank you. I was not clear on what the "/" meant here.  There's still something I'm not understanding because I'm getting a "syntax error" at "function flush_buff("test.txt") where "test.txt" is my file name of the file I want to split.  I will update my code in my question so this is clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196517/discussion-between-zelnes-and-ant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @codeforester, `awk` seems to be a better choice. Here is a possible script that, I hope, does what you want.

```
BEGIN {
    # Field separator are all but digits because we are only interested in
    # two kind of digit : row number and time step
    FS = "[^0-9]+"
    # Buffer line counter
    bl = 1
    # Base output directory
    BASE_DIR="/tmp/large_dir/"
}
# Function to buffer the current line
function save_line() {
    buff[bl++] = $0 "\n"
}
# Flush buffer into the given file and reset it
function flush_buff(file) {
    for (i = 1; i < bl; ++i)
        printf(buff[i]) >>file
    bl = 1
    delete buff
    close(file)
}
# Main program
{
    # Retrieve the number of line, save it and move to next line
    row = $2; save_line(); getline
    # Retrieve the step number and save the line
    step = $2; save_line()
    # Loop for row lines
    for (i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        getline
        save_line()
    }
    # Create the current directory (concatenation of BASE_DIR and current step)
    cur_dir = BASE_DIR step
    system("mkdir -p " cur_dir)
    # Flush the buffer to "file" in the cur_dir directory
    flush_buff(cur_dir "/file")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for this, Zeines.  It will take me a while to go through it and figure out how to adapt it.  I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Zeines I'm working through this; thanks a lot.  I figured out how to run it up to the end of the BEGIN function by making a small change (added: awk 'BEGIN...}') and can now run to there.  However, I am getting ""syntax error near unexpected token 'file' 'function flush_buff(file) {' and am working on that.

Comment: @Ant can you provide the code that gives you this error

Comment: That's very kind of you, Zeines.  I will post it in my question as an edit.  I have to go offline for a few hours, but will be back.

Answer (score 0):

if your file layout is strict, you can simplify the code dramatically

```
$ awk 'f&&f--      {split($3,x,","); output_file=x[1]".txt"} 
       file        {print > output_file} 
       !/[^ 0-9]/  {f=1; file=""}' input_file

$ head ?.txt
==> 0.txt <==
i =        0, time =        0.000, X =     -5862.450
Ir         2.7122680189       11.056957424         6.8765696187
Ir         1.7122680189        7.0569574242        2.8765696187
Ir         10.1738894899      10.9594639697       10.1225475792
Ir         1.7122680189       10.5695742424        2.8765696187
Ir         0.8778827417       -0.5336942397        0.4088988234
XO         0.1738894899        6.9594639697       -2.1225475792
XO        -8.0921793354        6.4673780979        2.6251511813
XO        -5.1738894899       -0.9594639697       -7.1225475792
XO         4.1738894899       -7.9594639697       12.1225475792

==> 1.txt <==
i =        1, time =        1.000, X =     -5862.450
Ir         2.7122680189       11.056957424         6.8765696187
Ir         1.7122680189        7.0569574242        2.8765696187
Ir         10.1738894899      10.9594639697       10.1225475792
Ir         1.7122680189       10.5695742424        2.8765696187
Ir         0.8778827417       -0.5336942397        0.4088988234
XO         0.1738894899        6.9594639697       -2.1225475792
XO        -8.0921793354        6.4673780979        2.6251511813
XO        -5.1738894899       -0.9594639697       -7.1225475792
XO         4.1738894899       -7.9594639697       12.1225475792
```

change the filename according to your needs, I just used the step number suffixed by ".txt", note that you can't use `0` by itself since it will be decoded as `false` or `null`.

Comment: @karafka, thanks. I tried this, but have not been successful.  Here's what I did.  I ran each of the top three lines via the command line in the same directory where I store my test file, called "test-pos.txt."  I first ran the code as-is.  Then I tried substituting "test-pos" in place of "x" and "x[1]" on the top line.  The first time, I got "can't open file file" and the second time, "syntax error at source line 1" and "illegal statement on line 2."

Comment: your input file should be the file after the script.  Unfortunately I reused the same name.  Output file names is set in the variable called file in the script.  Here I only add ".txt" the extracted step number stored in the array position `x[1]`.  `x` is an internal variable not related to your input file.  Run the script as is and just the last `file` replaced with the actual input filename.

Comment: I better rename them to eliminate confusion.